# Error - At least one public class is required in main file java?

Tags: java

**My Code:**

```
class Emp {} 
class Manager extends Emp{}
class Director extends Manager {} 
class Test{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Emp e = new Emp(); Director d = new Director();
          System.out.println(e instanceof Object); 
          System.out.println(d instanceof Object); 
          System.out.println(d instanceof Director); 
          System.out.println(d instanceof Manager); 
          System.out.println(d instanceof Emp); 
     }
}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
true
```

**Actual Output:**
    *Error - At least one public class is required in main file java?*

Comment: This code compiles and runs fine. That doesn't look like a real error message.

Comment: It looks like it is an error message from the environment you are using to compile and run it, e.g. your IDE.

Answer (score 3):

The provided code is perfectly fine. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/izA6B8).

It seems that  you are missing something else and have not provided some other information which may be helpful in this case.

**It seems that you are putting `Test` class in a `package`. If so, do following:**

- Change the visibility of `Test` class as public i.e. `public class Test` AND
- Save the file as `Test.java`

Answer (score 2):

Make the signature for your main class public, as the error message suggests.

```
 public class Test{
```

...
and of course keep it in Test.java

Comment: Naming the class `Test` and saving it in `test.java` won't work

Comment: Corrected, it should be Test.java

Comment: It should be pointed out that If this fixes the problem, it's because the OP's choice of IDE makes additional restrictions on the code. Java itself is perfectly happy running `main` from a non-public class.

Answer (score 1):

Just write public in front of your class

```
public class Test
```

Comment: A class containing `main` does not have to be public. It is probably the user's IDE that can't find the main class because he hasn't told the IDE what the main class is called.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the online compiler may not understand this but the code is perfectly fine. For an online compiler, you can run by inserting the `public` keyword in front of `class`

```
`public class Emp {} 
 class Manager extends Emp{}
 class Director extends Manager {} 
 class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Emp e = new Emp(); Director d = new Director();
      System.out.println(e instanceof Object); 
      System.out.println(d instanceof Object); 
      System.out.println(d instanceof Director); 
      System.out.println(d instanceof Manager); 
      System.out.println(d instanceof Emp); 
    }
}`
```